# Help Delphi And Sql Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, delphi

When I run these codes I get this error: parameter object is improperly defined...

```
ADOStoredProc1.Parameters.ParamByName('@InDocNo').Value:=QuotedStr('784');
ADOStoredProc1.Parameters.ParamByName('@inStart').Value:=QuotedStr('1');
ADOStoredProc1.Parameters.ParamByName('@InEnd').Value:=QuotedStr('1');
ADOStoredProc1.Parameters.ParamByName('@InPrintType').Value:='2';
ADOStoredProc1.Parameters.ParamByName('@InRecNo').Value:=QuotedStr('1');
ADOStoredProc1.ExecProc
```

Comment: Please post a more complete code example. Also, what version of Delphi are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to use the "@" when you use ParamByName for the stored procedure variable.  If you take that out, I believe it will work.